# Unreal Engine : from character to vehicle with Possess

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint, unreal-engine5

I start playing with a character, and when I press C, I can possess the vehicle but it doesn't move at all, as if I loose all the input. But if I change the gamemode of the level to start with the vehicle, it works fine. What's wrong with the blueprint I use ?

PS : I used the default templates of Unreal for the third person character et the vehicle character, so I have a "vehiclePlayerController"
[image]

Function in the car blueprint :
[image]

How I call the function from the character blueprint :
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have diffrent types of input mappings, you have to "add mapping context" and select the mapping context you created for the car. The target is "Enhanced Input Local Player Subsystem" of "Get Player Controller"